# Why is the local certificate store missing in Windows 8.1?

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate, trusted-root-certificates

I am trying to import a self-signed certificate into the local certificate store of the Trusted Root CAs on my Windows 8.1 machine, but that store is missing. Importing it into the Trusted Root CAs store doesn't work (i.e. browsers keep telling me that the certificate is not trusted).

So basically what I am looking for is this:

[image]

My user account also had administrator rights on the machine, if it can help.

Comment: this a personal pc or company pc?

Comment: @Ramhound it's a personal PC

Comment: What do you mean by "local certificate store" and what error message are you getting?

Comment: @harrymc image added. Also, no error message, that store is simply not there.

Comment: What certificate type are you trying to import? It by default will only show X.509 unless you choose another type.

Comment: Could you also include the screenshot of the dialog on the Windows 8.1 computer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One can edit the certificates on the local computer this way:

1. Start → Run: `mmc.exe`
2. Menu: *File* → *Add/Remove Snap-in*…
3. Under *Available snap-ins*, select *Certificates* and press *Add*.
4. Select *Computer Account* for the certificates to manage. Press *Next*.
5. Select *Local Computer* and press *Finish*.
6. Press *OK* to return to the management console.

Once the local certificates are displayed:

1. Click to open "Trusted root Certificate Authorities"
2. Right-click on *Certificates* → *All tasks* → *Import*
3. Browse to your certificate to import it.

You can save this console for future use via the menu *File* → *Save As*.

Comment: Great thanks! I guess they just removed that entry from Windows 8 then.

Comment: You can use preexisted console `certlm.msc` insted of create new one.

Comment: @PetSerAl: certlm.msc doesn't exist on all Windows versions, while mmc does.

Comment: so this seemed to work in Windows 8.1 until I rebooted, now Chrome is saying the certificate isn't trusted by the OS again...

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure the answer selected actually answered the question. I was adding the certificate plugin in mmc like everyone else. To no avail this never showed the "Local Computer " store.

Instead of looking for and opening `mmc.exe`, search for and open `certmgr.msc`. This opens certificates for the current user. You can then continue on as before, and it will show you the "Local Computer" store.